# get "parent" window of newly created window

Tags: x11

I need to get "parent" window of newly created window. For example: I start xterm, type "zenity --info" and I want to set zenity window geometry same as xterm geometry. I looked for XCreateWindowEvent (parent field) but that's not what I want. How I can to do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: xterm and other terminal emulators set WINDOWID environment variable which your program can read.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code:

```c
bool getWindowParent(Window & winId, Window & _root) {
    Window root, parent, *children = NULL;
    unsigned int num_children;

    if(!XQueryTree(m_display, winId, &root, &parent, &children, &num_children))
        return false;

    if (children)
        XFree((char *)children);

    winId = parent;
    _root = root;
    return true;
}
```